# foreach Loop Running Once

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops, foreach

So I'm having an issue with my foreach loop only running once.

I have the following data for the $file_url variable.

```
$file_url = "http://www.somedomain.com/12355/1.jpg,http://www.somedomain.com/12355/2.jpg,http://www.somedomain.com/12355/3.jpg,http://www.somedomain.com/12355/4.jpg";
```

Now my code looks like this:

```
function fetch_media($file_url,$vin,$cacheid) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    global $wpdb;

    if(!$vin) {
        $vin = $cacheid;
    }

    $vin = $vin . '/';

    //directory to import to    
    $artDir = "wp-content/uploads/vehiclephotos/$vin";

    //if the directory doesn't exist, create it 
    if(!file_exists(ABSPATH.$artDir)) {
        mkdir(ABSPATH.$artDir);
    }

    $file_url = explode(",", $file_url);
    $gallery_images = array();

    foreach ($file_url as $url) {

    //rename the file... alternatively, you could explode on "/" and keep the original file name
    $filename = array_pop(explode("/", $url));

        if (@fclose(@fopen($url, "r"))) { //make sure the file actually exists
            copy($url, ABSPATH.$artDir.$filename);

            $siteurl = get_option('siteurl');
            $file_info = getimagesize(ABSPATH.$artDir.$filename);

            //create an array of attachment data to insert into wp_posts table
            $artdata = array();
            $artdata = array(
                'post_author' => 1, 
                'post_date' => current_time('mysql'),
                'post_date_gmt' => current_time('mysql'),
                'post_title' => $filename, 
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'comment_status' => 'closed',
                'ping_status' => 'closed',
                'post_name' => sanitize_title_with_dashes(str_replace("_", "-", $filename)),
                'post_modified' => current_time('mysql'),
                'post_modified_gmt' => current_time('mysql'),
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'guid' => $siteurl.'/'.$artDir.$filename,
                'post_mime_type' => $file_info['mime'],
                'post_excerpt' => '',
                'post_content' => ''
            );

            $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
            $save_path = $uploads['basedir'].'/vehiclephotos/'.$vin.$filename;

            //insert the database record
            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($artdata, $save_path);

            //generate metadata and thumbnails
            if ($attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $save_path)) {
                wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
            }

            array_push($gallery_images,$attach_id);
            }

    }

    return serialize($gallery_images);
}
```

So the output I'm getting is the serialized array which is:

```
a:1:{i:0;i:103525;}
```

Which is fine, but since there were 4 array items, it should have looped 4 times and given me the serialized data with 4 attachment_id's.  All the other code in there runs fine once, it downloads the image from the URL, it renames it and creates all thumbnail sizes of the photo fine.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$fire_url != $file_url`

Comment: Hah that was a typo while writing it up, that's supposed to read file_url.

Comment: use `print_r($file_url)` before foreach and check if Array is being properly fetched

Comment: do a log statement as the first line in the `foreach`. I bet the loop is working fine and the issue is something with the logic inside.

Answer (score 0):

While troubleshooting, remove the `@-operator` to see what errors you get. So:

```
if (@fclose(@fopen($url, "r"))) { //make sure the file actually exists
```

becomes:

```
if (fclose(fopen($url, "r"))) { //make sure the file actually exists
```

You could probably simplify this line to:

```
if (file_exists($url)) {
```

Comment: This sort of helped to move along.  Looks like it was getting stuck at this part.  I took it out because I realized my URLs are live URLs so it's a 100% certainty that those files are there before I even get to this part.  The debugging continues though as it's still getting stuck with the import past the first photo.

Answer (score 0):

That code is fine. In all likelihood your inputs must therefore be at fault. As others intimate, the code you post doesn't suggest you are logging the `count()`. I would guess that the statement that the `$file_url` array has four items is in fact untrue.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($file_url as $url) {
try {

    //rename the file... alternatively, you could explode on "/" and keep the original file name
    $filename = array_pop(explode("/", $url));

        if (@fclose(@fopen($url, "r"))) { //make sure the file actually exists
            copy($url, ABSPATH.$artDir.$filename);

            $siteurl = get_option('siteurl');
            $file_info = getimagesize(ABSPATH.$artDir.$filename);

            //create an array of attachment data to insert into wp_posts table
            $artdata = array();
            $artdata = array(
                'post_author' => 1, 
                'post_date' => current_time('mysql'),
                'post_date_gmt' => current_time('mysql'),
                'post_title' => $filename, 
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'comment_status' => 'closed',
                'ping_status' => 'closed',
                'post_name' => sanitize_title_with_dashes(str_replace("_", "-", $filename)),
                'post_modified' => current_time('mysql'),
                'post_modified_gmt' => current_time('mysql'),
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'guid' => $siteurl.'/'.$artDir.$filename,
                'post_mime_type' => $file_info['mime'],
                'post_excerpt' => '',
                'post_content' => ''
            );

            $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
            $save_path = $uploads['basedir'].'/vehiclephotos/'.$vin.$filename;

            //insert the database record
            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($artdata, $save_path);

            //generate metadata and thumbnails
            if ($attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $save_path)) {
                wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
            }

            array_push($gallery_images,$attach_id);
            }

    }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

use try and catch in foreach loop it will keep on running as well as you can see the error whats wrong in foreach loop

Comment: Hmm tried this, but getting an error 500 after I saved the code.  I added a missing }, but still didn't fix it.

Comment: I was able to get your code to run, but it still didn't output any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue wasn't with the loop after all like someone mentioned.  I was getting an error copying the file over to my server after the first image...which is a whole different issue altogether.

Thank you for the guidance that led me to find the fault.